# How can I see processes running in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, process

I found the following sentence:

> Many Windows-Users may have wondered
>   about the mDNSResponder.exe process
>   running all the time. It’s Bonjour.

Does anybody know how can I see these processes (I do not mean "mDNSResponder.exe". I mean in general.). It should be some analog of "top" command in Linux.

Comment: In addition to the Task Manager others have mentioned, you can find some interesting info by using the Resource Monitor as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the windows command line you can use `tasklist` to list all running processes.

You can pipe the output of `tasklist` (as well as any other command line tool) using the "|" character.  I almost always use `tasklist` in this manner.

The GUI version is called the Task Manager and there are a number of ways to access it.

Comment: I also check all my process using this command

Comment: For a shortcut to the Task Manager do Ctrl+Shift+Esc and you should get Task Manager.

Comment: You can do clever things from the command prompt with the tasklist command like this also:

tasklist | find "bon" /i

Would find all running processes that match the pattern "bon".

Answer (score 14):

What you want may be satisfied by Task Manager (Ctrl-Shift-Esc), but in case you (or others reading this) want more information, another option (not built into Windows but supported by Microsoft) is [**Process Explorer**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from the Microsoft [**SysInternals suite**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals). It is *way* more useful if you want to do more with that list of processes and see more information. Very very useful to track down tricky system problems.

Process Explorer was developed by [**Mark Russinovich**](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/default.aspx), author of the various Windows Internals editions and now a Technical Fellow at Microsoft. It has an [**active support forum**](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_topics.asp?FID=2).

[image]

Comment: +1, this is a slick tool. Since MS bought SYSInternals a while back, one has to wonder why they don't drop task manager and replace it with this one. The process tree feature alone is great, but the search for open DLLs has saved me countless hours. It's just a superior tool.

Comment: @DCookie - absolutely. Was using this just yesterday to help figure out what was going on with a configuration file that was being ignored by an application. Invaluable.

Comment: @dco: For such a tool to be included with Windows it would have to go through many more hoops. It has to be officially supported, the code has to adhere to certain standards, it has to be tested in all kinds of ways, &c. It's *not* just a simple matter of including the program in the operating system; there is more work involved and a limited budget to spend. Also, most users probably wouldn't need it anyway—it'd be something that benefits a very small minority and thus it's even more understandable that the additional work is just not considered to be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You can view the processes by running the Task Manager.

[image]

Right-click an empty space in the taskbar and select Task Manager.
You'll also find a button to start it by triggering CTRL+ALT+DEL.

Comment: Right-click the taskbar. :-)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Esc c",)

Comment: @Svish yeah and you're right about the 'c' there  (chrome) ;-) bu..t it doesn't accumulate all the chromes into one. chrome menu..tools..task manager..nerd stats..scroll down biggest number. like 2.8GB for 41 tabs.

Comment: @barlop That `c` there is part of the awesome smiley `c",)` ;-)

Comment: @Svish That is blatantly obvious, and that is why I wrote a winking smiley after I wrote that about the 'c'.

Answer (score 1):

Task Manager can be called by Ctrl+Shirt+Esc. Or right-click on windows taskbar and select "Start task manager". Do not forget to check "Show processed from all users" if available.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `tasklist` from the `command-prompt`:

[image]

`Start` => `cmd` => hit <kbd>enter</kbd> => `tasklist`

---

for finding a specific process, you can run:

```
tasklist | find /i "myProcess"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find a process file on disk add the PID columns to task manager, read the process id and go in 
System Information (under start-> programs -> accessories -> system tools) 
In System Infromaton go to -> Software Environement -> Running Task and you can find the Path of every running process, with some others useful information...

Answer (score 0):

You can also view the paths of running processes in the vanilla task manager by adding the Command Line column to the process list (View > Select Columns)

Answer (score 0):

A built in program can reveal the running processes. Go to the command prompt (Type cmd in the Start search bar) and in the command window type qprocess. After pressing enter, a list of running processes follows.
If needed, the window can be stretched to show more of the results. Type exit to close the command window.

Comment: this indeed shows processes, sessions and users using them, but shows no usage on processor, memory etc as the QA suggests (`top` - like) . `taskmgr` would fit better.